# Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

In my project, I used `ng2-imageupload` and installed through `npm install ng2-imageupload`.
when I run it in `development mode`, it run perfectly but if I run in `production mode`, it gives an error like
 **Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'**

Comment: We have the same problem with MarkdownModule. I still have no idea what could possibly cause that. Do you use webpack?

Comment: yes .i am using webpack.i am using Udemy(site) seed project. which seed project are u using for develop angular -node project?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a circular dependency in your project structure. Make sure that you're not calling a module which cycles back to call the original module.